# Convert SQL databound datatable cell to string with 2 decimal places, VB.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, integer, decimal

I am currently working in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 with a SQL Server back end. I am using a SQL query to pull a datatable and then selecting the first cell to pull a number from. I need to take this number from the datatable and then change a label to show this number as either a 2 decimal number or a percentage would be even better. Here is my code:

```
    Try
        Dim Associates As Integer = NUPAssociates.Value
        Dim Hours As Integer = NUPHours.Value
        Dim WorkingHours As Integer = (Associates * Hours)
        ' MsgBox(WorkingHours)
        'sql connection
        Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
            conn1.Open()
            Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT ((sum([Time])/60)/@WorkHours) as EarnedHours FROM table1 " _
                                              & "Left Join table2 on table1.PartNumber + '-' = table2.PART_NUMBER " _
                                              & "WHERE col1  >= @start AND col1 < dateadd(day, 1, @Start) " _
                                              & "AND col2 = 25 AND col3 = 1 AND FloorNumber is not null and col4 > 30", conn1)
                comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", DTPStart.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkHours", WorkingHours)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim sql As New SqlDataAdapter(comm1)
                sql.Fill(dt)
                Dim EFF As String = dt.Rows(0).Item(0).value.ToString("N2")
                labeleff.Text = EFF
            End Using
            conn1.Close()
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: The sql query is perfect. I have ran the query in my microsoft sql server management studio management. My error I am getting is "System.MissingMemberException: Public 'value' on type 'Double' not found."

Comment: Is the function expecting a Double and you give it an Integer - `WorkingHours`

Comment: Perhaps, could it be that the number in the datable needs to be converted from integer to double and then to string?

Comment: I would try it - simple fix if so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access the value in the datatable cell with

```
dt.Rows(0).Item(0).value.ToString("N2")
```

but `dt.Rows(0).Item(0)` (or  simply `dt.Rows(0)(0)`) already return the value as an `object`. You use `value` property to retrieve the value from a DataGridViewCell.

The "right" way to do it would be:

```
CDbl(dt.Rows(0)(0)).ToString("N2")
```